# Should my View or ViewModel have the DataType assigned

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Which approach has a better maintainablility and extendability?

Where are the limitations/restrictions for each approach?

Put the DataType inside the ViewModel

OR

Put the DataType/Control type in the view?

**VIEWMODEL**

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string LongDescription { get; set; }
```

OR

**VIEW**

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.LongDescription)
```

Comment: You really need to define "better" here. Right now it's too subjective for me to provide a good answer.

Comment: Did an update? satisfied? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as maintainability is concerned, defining it in your view model would be best.

Given your example suppose we had this in our VM:

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string LongDescription { get; set; }
```

and this in our View:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.LongDescription);
```

Now lets say that some requirements have changed and a simple string no longer cuts it for your LongDescription, say you created a special `CustomRichTextFormat` class to store it. You would change your VM to look like the following:

```
public CustomRichTextFormat LongDescription { get; set; }
```

You can then create an EditorTemplate called `CustomRichTextFormat.cshtml` and put it in the `EditorTemplates` folder in your View folder, and since you used `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.LongDescription);` in your original View, MVC will be smart enough to show the custom editor you have defined for any fields of the `CustomRichTextFormat` type.

So to summarize, the advantage of this approach was that you have a truly generic View that doesn't require any changes despite the underlying type of the field changing in the ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion i would suggest having the ViewModel contain the DataType.  The reason is because you may then do something like this for your viewModel.

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m);
```

Which will decrease the amount of markup you need in your view.

Comment: Is less markup really better than less viewmodel 'markup'? Why? You did not really answer the question. I miss the exact advantage.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, it's more powerful to use `EditorFor`, as this tries to guess what editor you need for a given model element. It's intelligent enough to select custom editor templates where you have defined templates for a given type. For example, if you had a custom editor for images, you could just use the `EditorFor` syntax and the view engine will resolve the editor for you.

It's a good solution, because it keeps the amount of information repetition down; you only have to specify type information in one place, creating a single source of truth that other components can read from to make decisions. That also means if you make changes to the types of your model, the view will still produce a suitable editor for those types.

However, there are going to be occasions when `EditorFor` fails to produce the result you need, at which point you will have to get closer to the metal and invoke the appropriate `HtmlHelper` methods, or even creating extension methods yourself.

You will need to use both approaches; don't be worried about choosing one over the other, as they both fill different needs. Generally, `EditorFor` will do more for you with less code, but don't by shy about going around it in special cases.